# Concurrently and asynchronously write into a file with MSVC?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, file-io

Currently I am using a single thread and fseek/fwrite to save data into a large file in loop. But of course the saving is bottleneck. To remove this bottleneck, I think I can create a thread for asynchronous file write but this will block the file access in next iteration thread.

Is there any way to concurrently and asynchronously write into a file in Visual C/C++?

(OS is Windows)

Comment: It seems like you'd want one or the other but not necessarily both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CreateFile(), SetFilePointer(), and SetEndOfFile() to create and pre-size a file. Then use CreateFile() in your worker threads to open additional handles to the file, SetFilePointer() to seek to the desired offsets, and WriteFile() to write into it. As long as each call to CreateFile() grants FILE_SHARE_WRITE rights, you can open multiple handles with GENERIC_WRITE permissions at a time. Each handle maintains its own pointer in the file.

Comment: Skip `SetFilePointer` and use the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` fields in an `OVERLAPPED` structure.

Comment: I was about to try WriteFileEx but this solution sounds neat. I will try this first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function:

```
CreateFileMapping
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx

to memory map the output file to memory, and then you can have your multiple threads write to the memory concurrently.

More info about memory mapped files here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

Comment: This is probably the fastest solution.

Comment: I thought about this but it has 2GB limitation in 32 bit machine. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Paul, you can map any part of the file, then unmap it again. You don't have to map the whole thing into memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous IO functions, such as [WriteFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), allow concurrent access.  But it isn't clear to me how you think this will improve your throughput.